# VBA Code works for every row except the last one

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA code that runs through a .txt (Comma separated) file, does some calculations (**Works fine**), and then re-organizes the data (Adds some headers and moves all the data down one row, gets rid of irrelevant data, **Doesn't work on last row**) and spits out a new .csv file.  I think it has to do with the fact that I am bumping everything down by one row.

Here is the aforementioned code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
Application.Visible = False
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Choose and open the .TXT file for conversion
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to process a .TXT file for use in InfoSWMM?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Select .TXT File")
If answer = vbNo Then
    Application.Visible = True
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim Ret
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Do data conversion
Dim CountThem As Integer
Dim CountIt2 As Integer
Dim CountIt As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim ant As Double
Dim tester(3) As Double
Dim col_test As Integer
Dim size_test As Integer
Dim rim As Double
Dim Diff2Ele As Double
Dim ResultTxt As String
Dim DiamResultTxt As String
Dim DiamResult As Double
Dim CorrectedDiamResult As Double
Dim Result As Double
Dim MeasDiff As Double
Dim GetElev As Double
Dim GetDiam As String
Dim GetDiam_Val As Double
Dim SVal As Double
Dim Diam2Ft As Double
CountIt = 1
CountIt2 = 1
For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
    'Change these values in case feature code library is changed in Carlson, also need to add extra fields
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "SD" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "WQ" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "SDCS" Then
        col_test = 20
        size_test = 19
        rim = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value) 'Needs val to convert as double
        For i = 0 To 3
            Result = 0
            ResultTxt = Empty
            StringLength = Len(Cells(row, col_test))
            Str_Length = Len(Cells(row, size_test))
            'Gets numbers from string, but ignores 3rd char
            DiamResultTxt = Empty
            For j = 1 To StringLength
                If j = 3 Then GoTo NextIteration 'Skips to next loop on 3rd character, which is an irrelevant number (not one we want)
                If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(row, col_test), j, 1)) = True Or Mid(Cells(row, col_test), j, 1) = "." Then
                    ResultTxt = ResultTxt & Mid(Cells(row, col_test), j, 1)
                End If
NextIteration:
                Next j
                For j = 1 To Str_Length
                    If j = 3 Then GoTo nNextIteration 'Skips to next loop on 3rd character, which is an irrelevant number (not one we want)
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(row, size_test), j, 1)) = True Then
                        DiamResultTxt = DiamResultTxt & Mid(Cells(row, size_test), j, 1)
                    End If
nNextIteration:
                Next j
                'MsgBox ResultTxt
                DiamResult = Val(DiamResultTxt)
                CorrectedDiamResult = DiamResult / 12
                'MsgBox DiamResult
                Result = Val(ResultTxt) 'Needs val to convert as Double
                If (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 34).Value, "TOP") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 34).Value, "PIPE") > 0) Or (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 36).Value, "TOP") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 36).Value, "PIPE")) Or (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 38).Value, "TOP") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 38).Value, "PIPE")) Then
                    tester(i) = Result + CorrectedDiamResult
                Else
                    tester(i) = Result
                End If
                col_test = col_test + 4
                size_test = size_test + 4
            Next i
            Diff2Ele = WorksheetFunction.Max(tester)
            If Diff2Ele = 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 39).Value = "Unable to obtain"
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 39).Value = rim - Diff2Ele '39 is out of WQ SD and SDCS def. range
            End If
        End If
        'Corrects for top of pipe instances
        GetDiam = Empty
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "OUTFALL" Then
            If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 18).Value, "TOP") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 18).Value, "PIPE") > 0 Then
                GetElev = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value)
                kLen = Len(Cells(row, 16))
                For k = 1 To kLen
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(row, 16), k, 1)) = True Or Mid(Cells(row, 16), k, 1) = "." Then
                        GetDiam = GetDiam & Mid(Cells(row, 16), k, 1)
                    End If


           Next k
                GetDiam_Val = Val(GetDiam)
                Diam2Ft = GetDiam_Val / 12
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 39).Value = GetElev - Diam2Ft
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 39).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next row
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Prepare sheet re-organization, has to be next step to get altered data from prior process
    For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
        'ID
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 44).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value
        'Description
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 40).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value
        'Rim Elevation
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value <> "OUTFALL" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value <> "DITCH" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 41).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value
        End If
        'X pos
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 42).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value
        'Y pos
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 1, 43).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value
    Next row
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Re-organize sheet
    For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 44).Value) = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf CountIt = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = "ID"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = "DESC."
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value = "RIM ELEV."
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value = "YR_INST"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "YR_RETIRE"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 6).Value = "ZONE"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 7).Value = "PHASE"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 8).Value = "INV. ELEV."
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 9).Value = "DEPTH_RIM"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 10).Value = "INIT_DPTH"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 11).Value = "SURG_DPTH"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 12).Value = "POND_AREA"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 13).Value = "FLOOD_TYP"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 14).Value = "SD_COEFF"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 15).Value = "SELECTED"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 16).Value = "SYMBOL"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 17).Value = "SYMSIZE"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 18).Value = "X"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 19).Value = "Y"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 20).Value = "Z"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 21).Value = "SD_MESH"
            CountIt = CountIt + 1
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 44).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 40).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 41).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 6).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 7).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 8).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 39).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 9).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 10).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 11).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 12).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 13).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 14).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 15).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 16).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 17).Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 18).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 42).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 19).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 43).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 20).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 41).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 21).Value = ""
            For CountThem = 22 To 44
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, CountThem).Value = ""
            Next CountThem
        End If
    Next row
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Save converted file as .CSV
    MsgBox "Choose the desired save location for the .CSV file."
    Dim InitialName As String
    Dim PathName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    InitialName = "sfm_output"
    PathName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    MsgBox "Process completed successfully." & vbNewLine & "File saved to:" & vbNewLine & PathName
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Close all Workbooks
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

The section(s) in question are either the "Prepare sheet re-organization" section or the "Re-organize sheet section" (or both).  Sorry that the code is sloppy currently, I am just trying to get it to work in the first place before I go through and clean it up.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Not sure what happened with the indentation in the code snippet..

Edit2: Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/blasphemousjohn/swmm-converter) with the .xlsm file and a sample input .txt file.

Comment: We don't know what the input data is like, and thus cannot reproduce the situation.  Please set some breakpoints in your code, and look at intermediate status of the sheet to see where in your code the problem occurs.  Then set more breakpoints in the failing area, finally single step the code until the problem is found.

Comment: Here is the source .xlsm with a sample input .txt file (TALENT-LOUISJ-9-19.txt).  [Source](https://github.com/blasphemousjohn/swmm-converter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input data.  Please add

```
'at very top
Option Explicit

'after Dim answer As Integer
Application.Visible = True
Stop

'in data conversion
Dim StringLength As Long, Str_Length As Long, kLen As Long

'please note
'rows 14 & 15 are not SD, WQ, SDCS, but fall thru to OUTFALL, 
'but neither are TOP/PIPE because column tested s/b 19 (not 18)

'real problem is in Reorg
        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 44).Value) = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
 col-A  col-AM etc...

1                           
2       1641.11 SD  1644.01 4302311.81  216897.65   1
3       1641.63 SD  1644.53 4302261.52  216898  2
4       1648.61 SD  1651.26 4302009.62  216670.98   3
5       1648.99 SD  1652.39 4301918.39  216673.01   4
6       1649.51 SD  1654.41 4301857.91  216626.07   5
7       1651.74 SD  1654.64 4301628.69  216756.85   6
8       1662.07 SD  1665.12 4301234.27  216561.5    7
9       1661.76 SD  1665.02 4301232.65  216482.29   8
10      1661.14 SD  1664.94 4301271.11  216498.17   9
11      1669.14 SD  1669.29 4301040.07  216960.04   10
12      1656.85 SD  1661.1  4302020.09  216349.68   11
13      1658.6  SD  1660.64 4302036.86  216345.72   12
14      Unable..WQ  1656.83 4302020.95  216368.26   13
15      1647    OUTFALL 1647    4302151.24  216561.44   14
        1648.76 OUTFALL 1648.76 4302059.74  216518.98   15
```

Col=1 on row 16 is blank, and ExitFor is done one row too soon.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure what my thinking with the nested Ifs was at the time, but I changed it to:

`If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True And IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 44).Value) = True Then
            Exit For`

From:

`If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 44).Value) = True Then
                Exit For
            End If`

And it works now.  Also have made the additions you recommended, thanks.